# How to add validation for checkbox in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have an array of checkboxes including a hidden checkbox so i can send a value 0 if a checkbox is not checked.

```
@foreach($records as $record)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $record->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $record->id }}</td>

    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="record_checkbox[{{ $loop->index }}]" value="0" />

        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control name="record_checkbox[{{ $loop->index }}]" value="1" />

    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I want to validate that **only** `0` or `1` is sent when a user submits the form.

In my controller I have tried using this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'record_checkbox[]' => 'integer|boolean|min:0|max:1',
]);
```

But when I use browser developer tools and manually update the value field of `checkbox` to `100`, it still accepts it and stores it in database.

So how can I only allow `0` or `1` by proper validation?

Comment: `max1:` is this a typo ? I guess it should be `max:1`

Comment: But why would that be a problem? Php will always see `0` as `false`, and all other values as `true`

Comment: actually if i enter some value such as 50,100 in value attribute of checkbox it was actually storing that value and not 1.

Answer (score 3):

Remove brackets if you want to validate all array inputs:

```
$this->validate($request, [
      'record_checkbox' => 'in:0,1',
]);
```

**Edit**

Create custom rule: inside `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` under `boot` method add the following:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

...

public function boot() {

    Validator::extend('validate_checkboxes', function ($attribute, $values, $parameters, $validator) {

        foreach( $values as $value ) {
            if (!in_array($value, [0, 1])) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    });

}
```

And then in your controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
      'record_checkbox' => 'validate_checkboxes',
]);
```

Comment: it was working in the start but again its not working. what could be the reason ?

Comment: Try to use `name=record_checkbox[]` without `$loop->index`

Comment: but i did that for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138165/how-to-send-all-checkboxes-whether-checked-or-unchecked-on-form-submit

Comment: even after doing so it shows the error: The selected record checkbox is invalid.

Comment: So if you pass value other than 1 or 0 it's stored in the database ? what's the problem exactly

Comment: yes if i pass value like 50,100 it is also stored in database. but if i use your validation code then it  gives error for normal case as well, that is, for 0 and 1 also

Comment: the error returned is: The selected record checkbox is invalid

Comment: I think This is normal because you entered value different to 0 or 1

Comment: no but it also gives the same error when i provide it 0 or 1 value.

Comment: I see now, Try to use [boolean](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-boolean) validation rule: `'record_checkbox' => 'boolean',`

Comment: still same problem it gives same error even for 0 or 1 values but if i remove validation completely it does not give error for 0 or 1 but it then also allows values like 59,60 etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162757/discussion-between-raj-and-younel).

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to find a good answer to this for about a month and I think I finally got a good solution, so I'll share it.  I have something similar, where I have like 3 or 4 checkbox fields that determine tiny int switches in my database.  The way I did this is to add this line in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:

```
Validator::extendImplicit('checkbox', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        $data = $validator->getData();
        $data[$attribute] = ($value == "1" || strtolower($value) == "true" || strtolower($value) == "on")? "1": "0";
        $validator->setData($data);
        return true;
    });
```

Explanation:

```
Validator::extendImplicit
```

This makes sure that, regardless of whether the attribute is in the request object or not (and if it was unchecked it **will not be**) it will still run this rule anyways.

```
$data = $validator->getData();
$data[$attribute] = ($value == "1" || strtolower($value) == "true" || strtolower($value) == "on")? "1": "0";
$validator->setData($data);
```

Once we enter this function we will get the data array and add the entry for the checkbox as either a 0 or a 1 (note I'm not changing the request object, although you could do that too with something like request->merge() or request()->add()), it then sets the new data array.  So in your controller you would simply:

```
$data = $request->validate(['record_checkbox' => 'checkbox']);
```

And your data array will contain the field 'record_checkbox' set to either 0 or 1.  You can now use this array to fill() your model.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let try:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$request->validate([
'record_checkbox[]' => [
    'required|in_array:[0, 1]'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: this is not solving the problem. it still accepts values like 50,100 and stores in table